# Issue with datatype of Date in Informatica

Tags: java, etl, informatica-powercenter

I created a reusable transformation in which I have an input port of date/time format.

Now when I use this date/time port in my java code it gives me incompatible error long/date.

So I changed the input port of java transformation to String and used this string variable in java transformation. But even this code is giving me an error.

```
Severity    Timestamp   Node    Thread  Message Code    Message
INFO    26-04-2016 16:55:30 node01_Gizmo    READER_1_1_1    RR_4049 RR_4049 SQL Query issued to database : (Tue Apr 26 16:55:30 2016)
INFO    26-04-2016 16:55:30 node01_Gizmo    READER_1_1_1    RR_4050 RR_4050 First row returned from database to reader : (Tue Apr 26 16:55:30 2016)
INFO    26-04-2016 16:55:30 node01_Gizmo    READER_1_1_1    BLKR_16019  Read [10] rows, read [0] error rows for source table [CUSTOMERS] instance name [CUSTOMERS]
INFO    26-04-2016 16:55:30 node01_Gizmo    READER_1_1_1    BLKR_16008  Reader run completed.
INFO    26-04-2016 16:55:30 node01_Gizmo    TRANSF_1_1_1    JAVA PLUGIN_1762    [DEBUG] Unparseable using java.text.SimpleDateFormat@9586200
ERROR   26-04-2016 16:55:30 node01_Gizmo    TRANSF_1_1_1    JTX_1005    [ERROR] Column name [05/06/1998 00:00:00.000000] is invalid.
INFO    26-04-2016 16:55:30 node01_Gizmo    TRANSF_1_1_1    JTX_1015    [DEBUG] Exception thrown from Java transformation: [Column name [05/06/1998 00:00:00.000000] is invalid.].
ERROR   26-04-2016 16:55:30 node01_Gizmo    TRANSF_1_1_1    JAVA PLUGIN_1762    [ERROR] Column name [05/06/1998 00:00:00.000000] is invalid.
ERROR   26-04-2016 16:55:30 node01_Gizmo    TRANSF_1_1_1    JAVA PLUGIN_1762    [ERROR]     at com.informatica.powercenter.server.jtx.JTXPartitionDriverImplFixed.isNull(JTXPartitionDriverImplFixed.java:737)
ERROR   26-04-2016 16:55:30 node01_Gizmo    TRANSF_1_1_1    JAVA PLUGIN_1762    [ERROR]     at com.informatica.powercenter.server.jtx.JTXPartitionDriverImplGen.execute(JTXPartitionDriverImplGen.java:223)
ERROR   26-04-2016 16:55:30 node01_Gizmo    TRANSF_1_1_1    TM_6085 A fatal error occurred at  transformation [DateFormat], and the session is terminating. 
ERROR   26-04-2016 16:55:30 node01_Gizmo    TRANSF_1_1_1    TM_6085 A fatal error occurred at  transformation [SQ_CUSTOMERS], and the session is terminating. 
ERROR   26-04-2016 16:55:30 node01_Gizmo    TRANSF_1_1_1    TM_6085 A fatal error occurred at  transformation [SQ_CUSTOMERS], and the session is terminating. 
ERROR   26-04-2016 16:55:30 node01_Gizmo    TRANSF_1_1_1    TM_6085 A fatal error occurred at  transformation [SQ_CUSTOMERS], and the session is terminating. 
DEBUG   26-04-2016 16:55:30 node01_Gizmo    TRANSF_1_1_1    DBG_21511   TE: Fatal Transformation Error.
INFO    26-04-2016 16:55:30 node01_Gizmo    WRITER_1_*_1    WRT_8167    Start loading table [DateFormat] at: Tue Apr 26 16:55:30 2016
INFO    26-04-2016 16:55:30 node01_Gizmo    WRITER_1_*_1    WRT_8333    Rolling back all the targets due to fatal session error.
ERROR   26-04-2016 16:55:30 node01_Gizmo    WRITER_1_*_1    WRT_8170    Writer run terminated: Abort Session request received from the DTM
INFO    26-04-2016 16:55:30 node01_Gizmo    WRITER_1_*_1    WRT_8168    End loading table [DateFormat] at: Tue Apr 26 16:55:30 2016
INFO    26-04-2016 16:55:30 node01_Gizmo    WRITER_1_*_1    WRT_8035    Load complete time: Tue Apr 26 16:55:30 2016

LOAD SUMMARY
============

WRT_8036 Target: DateFormat (Instance Name: [DateFormat1])
WRT_8044 No data loaded for this target



INFO    26-04-2016 16:55:30 node01_Gizmo    WRITER_1_*_1    WRT_8043    *****END LOAD SESSION*****
```

Day is an output port of type String. The below is the code used in java transformation:

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter;
formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
Date my_date = null;
try{
    my_date = formatter.parse(Inp_Date);
}
catch(Exception e) { 
          System.out.println("Unparseable using " + formatter); 
      }
    formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("d");
    Day=formatter.format(my_date);
```

Please let me know how to use date/time variable in java transformation.

Regards,
Dex.

Answer (score 0):

You should use an expression transformation with the expression `TO_CHAR(inp_Date,'dd')` to do such conversions.

In your Java code the format string (dd-MM-yyyy) does not match the input date format (05/06/1998 00:00:00.000000). It should probably be changed to something like this:

```
formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS");
```

Comment: This format didn't work. I understand it can be done using expression transformation but what am looking for is how to read DateTime input in java transformation.